# MySQL-What's the difference between these two sql?CASE WHEN in MAX(),one uses null,one uses a character

Tags: mysql, sql

Data source as follows:

```
name    course
---------------
Marry   UNIX
Bob     Java
Bob     SQL
Cherry  SQL
John    SQL
John    UNIX
Eric    SQL
```

this sql is correct:

```
 SELECT  name,
    max(CASE WHEN course = 'SQL' THEN '○' ELSE null END) AS "SQL",
    max(CASE WHEN course = 'UNIX' THEN '○' ELSE null END) AS "UNIX",
    max(CASE WHEN course = 'Java' THEN '○' ELSE null END) AS "Java"
 FROM Courses
 GROUP BY name;
```

but this is wrong:

```
 SELECT  name,
    max(CASE WHEN course = 'SQL' THEN '○' ELSE 'x' END) AS "SQL",
    max(CASE WHEN course = 'UNIX' THEN '○' ELSE 'x' END) AS "UNIX",
    max(CASE WHEN course = 'Java' THEN '○' ELSE 'x' END) AS "Java"
 FROM Courses
 GROUP BY name;
```

I ran the second one in MySQL,and the result is wrong

```
    name    SQL   UNIX   JAVA
    Bob     x      x      x
    Cherry  ○      x      x
    Eric    ○      x      x
    John    x      x      x
    Marry   x      ○      x
```

so what's the problem between these two sql? MAX() ignore null?

Comment: Everything seems fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d23200/1

Comment: I ran the second one in MySQL,and the result is wrong
name   SQL  UNIX JAVA
Bob          x x      x
Cherry ○ x x
Eric         ○ x x
John x x x
Marry x ○ x

Comment: What version are you running?

Comment: MySQL version 8.0.18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MAX()` ignores null values, and picks the max value otherwise seen. Since `'x'` is larger than `'o'`, if both values are present, the result is `'x'`.

E.g. for Bob, since there are 2 records with different `course` value, at least one of the record will hit the `else` clause. Which means that for all 3 of them, at least one `'x'` is present, and so the result is `'x'` for all 3.

Basically, the first version is: "If the `WHEN` clause is true for *any* record, the result is `'o'`, otherwise the result is `NULL`."

The second version is: "If the `WHEN` clause is false for *any* record, the result is `'x'`, since that is the highest value, otherwise the result is `'o'`." Or said another way: "If the `WHEN` clause is true for *all* records, the result is `'o'`, otherwise the result is `'x'`."

Comment: thank you very much,I know what you mean.but i think whether 'x' is larger than 'o' or not,if when clause is false,the new value will cover the old value.

Comment: but why the answer is correct here:[http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d23200/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d23200/1)?

Comment: @H-X-P Because that `○` is not an `o` (lowercase letter O), but a [Unicode Character 'WHITE CIRCLE' (U+25CB)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25cb/index.htm), and is hence higher than `x`, which means "If the WHEN clause is true for *any* record, the result is ''○'', otherwise the result is `'x'`."

Comment: omg,i didn't notice that's not an `o`.^_^.but i got a new question.Use `Max(CASE WHEN course = 'SQL' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)` as an example,if the when clause is true,the result is 1,then why's the final result can be 2?Is there a 2 in a column so Max() pick the large one?

Comment: @H-X-P If there is *any* record where the condition is false, then the `CASE` expression evaluates to `2`, so `MAX()` will see a `2` and return that. --- Given that you only expect one record in a group to evaluate to true, it means that any group with more than one record, where one of the records evaluates to true, there will be records for both outcomes, so the result of `max()` will always be the higher of the two values. When the false value is higher, it means that for any group with more than one record, the condition check is meaningless, since you *will* get the `ELSE` value.